# How do you remove certain characters from a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
| city             |
| ---------------- |
| Chicago (IL IN)  |
| New (NY) York    |
| (ARZ) Phoenix    |
```

Is there a way to remove `(IL IN)`, `(NY)`, and `(ARZ)`?

I've tried the code below but it doesn't work.

```
UPDATE table
SET city = REPLACE(city, '(%)', '')
WHERE city LIKE '%(%)%'
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Will there be any `city` value that looks like this, `Xxxxx (XX) Xxxxx`?

Comment: @FanoFN, I believe it is 8.0.27, and yes some rows have that. I updated the question, thank you

Comment: I suggest you better define all the data scenarios and put them in edit at once. What are the maximum characters in the parentheses that appears in your table? Your current edit made the `REGEXP_REPLACE` suggested by @Ajax1234 doesn't work with all the values. I really think this can be easily done using `REGEXP_REPLACE` function but need to take consideration of all the data scenarios.

Comment: @FanoFN Yeah that's my bad. REGEXP REPLACE works as per Ajax, I just did not write down the whole situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp_replace`:

```
update table set city = regexp_replace(city, '\\(\\w{2,}(\\s\\w{2,})*\\)', '')
```

Comment: This seemed to work partially. For some reason, it didn't change all the columns.

Comment: @gaphalpa Please see my recent edit, as I removed the end of line character (`$`) from the expression to match city names with abbreviations that are padded with subsequent characters.

Comment: yes it worked, however I forgot to put in the question that not all of the characters inside the parenthesis have the same length. Sorry about that

Comment: Hi @Ajax1234 it fixed most of the rows, however it cant seem to remove the ones where (%) is at the end of the string

Comment: @gaphalpa Check out this fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=de122e04fa98b248d44e3690a2feb471

Comment: Hey @Ajax1234 sorry again I forgot to include that some of them have spaces in between like (IL IN). This is the one it cant seem to remove

Comment: @gaphalpa Please see my recent edit.

Answer (score 1):

This might work, it also removes extra space if any

```
update table1
set city = regexp_replace(city, '\\([\\w\\s]+\\)\\s*|\\s*\\([\\w\\s]+\\)', '')
where city like '%(%)%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running this and see what is the result:

```
SELECT city, 
       CONCAT(SUBSTRING(city,1,LOCATE('(',city)-1),SUBSTRING(city,LOCATE(')',city)+2)) AS trimmed_city
FROM mytable
WHERE city LIKE '%(%)%';
```

If the result of `trimmed_city` is what you want, then you can update it like:

```
UPDATE table
SET city=CONCAT(SUBSTRING(city,1,LOCATE('(',city)-1),SUBSTRING(city,LOCATE(')',city)+2)
WHERE city LIKE '%(%)%';
```

This probably for older MySQL version that doesn't support `REGEXP_REPLACE()` like [@Ajax1234's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69804257/10910692).

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question since not all of the (%) are in the end of the string.

Comment: I noticed. I think `REGEXP_RPLACE` can work but I'm not too familiar with it's functionality. I can suggest an alternative method.